# How to save the ouput of a python file using subprocess and append all those in a single file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, subprocess

Have a python code that generates different output everytime i run that.

How to save the all ouput that has been generated when i run that python script on loop using suprocess

Code I am using is overwriting the file not appending.

```
f = open("blah.txt", "w")
subprocess.call(["python","loop.py"], stdout=f)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your file in `append` mode ('a')

```
f = open("blah.txt", "a")
```

```
Mode    Description
---     ---
'r'     This is the default mode. It Opens file for reading.
'w'     This Mode Opens file for writing.
If file does not exist, it creates a new file.
If file exists it truncates the file.
'x'     Creates a new file. If file already exists, the operation fails.
'a'     Open file in append mode.
If file does not exist, it creates a new file.
't'     This is the default mode. It opens in text mode.
'b'     This opens in binary mode.
'+'     This will open a file for reading and writing (updating)
```

Answer (score 0):

open file in append mode instead of write mode

and if u want error also to be logged in the same file then.

```
f = open("blah.txt", "a")

subprocess.call(["python","loop.py"], stdout=f,stderr=f)
```